# Cypress: table contains specific row

Tags: cypress

With a table looking like this:

| TH1 | TH2 | TH3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | a |
| a | b | c |
| b | b | c |

can Cypress check that the table contains the row a, b, c ?
(bonus question: what if I have some more columns, but I don't care about their content, I just want to check that I have a row where 3 columns have the expected content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a helper function to map rows to arrays

```js
function rowCells(row) {
  return Cypress._.map(row.children, (cell) => cell.innerText)
}

cy.get('table tbody tr')
  .then(rows => Cypress._.map(rows, rowCells))
  .should('deep.eq', [['a','b','a'],['a','b','c'],['b','b','c']])

  .its('1')  // 2nd row
  .should('deep.eq', ['a','b','c'])
```

or if you want to dissect the array, use a `.then()` callback

```js
cy.get('table tbody tr')
  .then(rows => Cypress._.map(rows, rowCells))
  .then(tableData => {
    expect(tableData[1])to.deep.eq(['a','b','c'])
  })
```

---

**Take only first 3 columns**

```js
function rowCells(row) {
  const cells = [...row.children].slice(0,3)  // define which columns here
  return Cypress._.map(cells, (cell) => cell.innerText)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine something like:

```
const results: string[] = [];
cy.get('tr')
  .each((line: JQuery) => {
        const row = []
        line.find('td').foreach(column=>row.push(column.textContent.trim()))
        result.push(row)
      });
    });
  .then(()=>{
     expect(result)... // Assertion on result to find the desired text
   })
```